# EventEmitter: simultaneous events blend, how to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, angular

To receive events from multiple child components in one parent component
I pass event channel from parent (ProjectsComponent) to each child component (ProjectHeaderComponent)

projects.component.ts

```
  projects: Project[];
  editing = false;
  channel: EventEmitter<boolean>;

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) {
    this.channel = new EventEmitter<boolean>(false);
    this.channel.subscribe(isEditing => {
      this.editing = isEditing;
      console.log(this.editing);
    });
  }
```

projects.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let project of projects">
    <project-header [project]="project" [isEditing]="channel"></project-header>
</div>
```

project-header.component.ts

```
  @Input() project: Project;
  @Input() isEditing: EventEmitter<boolean>;

  set editing(data: boolean) {
    //....
    this.isEditing.emit(this._editing);
  }
```

project-header.component.html

```
<input type="text" (click)="toggleEditing()">
```

But if I already on one input and click on another, events blend and I receive `true, false`, rather than `false, true`

I tried to wrap `this.editing = isEditing;` with `setTimeout(() => this.editing = isEditing, 0);` but that not work.

Comment: It's hard to give any advice when we don't know where's the property `editing` used. Otherwise this code looks fine to me and should work as you want (if I understand correctly what you need).

Comment: Thank you, @Martin, adding on open event to bottom of call stack with setTimeout as in answer looks fine, I stop at this, thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of hacks  - events about open must arrive after close

```
  set editing(data: boolean) {
      /*on close*/
      if (!this._editing) {
        this._editedService.changeEdited(this._editing);
      } else /*on open*/ {
        setTimeout(() => this._editedService.changeEdited(this._editing), 0);
      }
  }
```